Is it possible to use a global error handler to show a react error component instead of a broken component
I use the react-error-boundary library, is there no way to make a global error component in it, so that when any component breaks, an error component is substituted instead, while IT is IMPORTANT that the application continues its work, only the broken component is replaced. Maybe you should use another library for this?
The main thing is not to wrap each component in error boundary, but the entire application and the problem area itself should be wrapped in error boundary.
When an error occurs in any component in the application, it does not break with a white screen, the non-working component is replaced by ErrorComponent.
I will be glad of any help.
This code is not suitable for the solution:
export const App = withErrorBoundary(() => (
    <div className="maincontainer">
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={routerHistory}>
                <Localization>
                    <Navigation />
                </Localization>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    </div>
), {
    onError: (...params) => {
        console.log("params", params)
    },
    FallbackComponent: ErrorBoundary
})


The main thing is not to wrap each component in error boundary  I would say that's pretty much the solution, you could certainly automate this.  Handling every component would not really be ideal either, as lots of components can be none-visual, or very small etc.  Some form of boundary level ideally wants setting.   Eg. on a website that has widgets, wrap each widget in an error boundary etc.
